# Push locally committed changes to new branch

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, commit

I am currently in `master` branch, I have committed the changes (locally) and tried to push it but it got rejected because I don't have access to push to `master` branch. Now I have created another branch `dev` where I have the permission to push.

Since I have already committed locally to master branch, how do I push these committed changes of `master` to `dev` branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your remote is named `origin`,

```
git push origin master:dev
```

would achieve it by explicitly giving source and destination. See it explained in [this paragraph](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203).

This can be run from any branch as it's not using current branch for anything.

Comment: I have to run above command in master branch or in dev branch?